# How to encode Kurdi font in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding, fonts

I want to type **جؤرةكان** ( Kurdi word ) in string.xml file in correct format ( جؤرةكان is wrong format ).
the problem might be  wrong encoding of the android studio or something else ...

Can anyone help me through this ?

[image: Correct Format of جؤرةكان is shown here]

Comment: what is the correct format?

Comment: the correct format link is added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I've found a solution
Installed kurdi keyboard ( Sorani keyboard => arabic-Iraq language ) & type the word again in the android studio string.xml file !!

the problem is solved.